# IzPack 5.1 - use user input variables in bash script without substitution

Tags: installation, substitution, izpack

Hopefully someone could help me here with following problem – tried to find a solution for this for weeks but unfortunately wasn’t able to find one.

I am using IzPack (recently updated to 5.1) as an installer for a software package. This package contains multiple executable files (bash scripts) which use variables inside. These variables are filled with values provided by the user during the installation process (user input panel).
The problem I have is that all these values get substituted in the bash-file if it is marked as “parsable” – otherwise (if not marked as “parsable”) the values are not substituted but it is not possible to access them during script execution. I have to access the values of these variables but it is no option for me to substitute them in the bash scripts because these files are not deleted after the installation is done and have to stay on the disk. In case of variable substitution all variables, also passwords, are substituted and could be seen by everybody, having read access to the file, in plaintext.

Has anyone got a solution or idea how this could be achieved using izPack? I also thought about encrypting the passwords – there exists a processor for it in izPack but unfortunately no documentation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about sanitizing or removing the files in question using the ProcessPanel?

This is typically run after the InstallPanel and before the installation is finished.